# Reverse proxying containerized angular app

Tags: docker, nginx, routes

We have an **angular_app** that upon running `docker-compose up` is accessible from
under `localhost`.

Now, we have another dockerized Nginx app that reverses proxies several apps. /app_A  /app_B /**agular_app**. Now A and B work already but the **angular_app** gives 502.

A snippet from Nginx

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://agular_app:5001;
}
```

A snippet from the docker file

```
agular_app:
  image: docker_repo/agular_app:latest
  ports:
    - 5001:80
```

The angular_app is accessible from localhost:5001
but not  accessible from localhost  (gives 502)

I have tried the following things:

- Yes, changing 5001:5001, the dame 502
- Different Nginx config such as adding proxy_set_header etc
- Tried not using redirects over proxy_pass

For me... The missing puzzle piece is... Why reverse proxy does not work. Again, the dockerized angular image running manually (not containerized) on Nginx works fine.

Here is the docker file for **angular_app**

```
# Stage 1

FROM node:12-alpine3.12 as build-step
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2

FROM nginx:1.14.2-alpine

COPY --from=build-step /app/frontend/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx_docker.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

Error from Nginx log upon calling localhost:

```
gateway          | 2021/05/27 06:52:07 [error] 28#28: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.2:5
001/", host: "localhost"
gateway          | 2021/05/27 06:52:07 [error] 28#28: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.2:5
001/502.html", host: "localhost"
gateway          | 172.18.0.1 - - [27/May/2021:06:52:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36" "-"
gateway          | 2021/05/27 06:52:07 [error] 28#28: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://1
72.18.0.2:5001/favicon.ico", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
gateway          | 2021/05/27 06:52:07 [error] 28#28: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://1
72.18.0.2:5001/502.html", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
```

Comment: If the process inside the target container is listening on port 80, the `proxy_pass` needs to use that port too (since it's the default HTTP port you can also remove it; `http://agular_app`).

Comment: @DavidMaze, thank you very much! 

Following fix works! 
`
port: 5001 
And removing port: 5001 from the proxy_pass 
`
Still, when I now add a 'location' to the app, it does not show up. 

`location /agular_app {
   proxy_pass http://agular_app:5001;
}
`